# CKEditor: Images with captions can't be centered?

Tags: 8

Drupal: 8.6.10
CKEditor: 4.10.1

Using the DrupalImage plugin along with the data-caption and data-align filters I am able to float images left and right, but never centered if the image also has a caption.

My image code in CKEditor:

```
<img alt="Some alt text" data-align="center" data-caption="Woot, a caption!" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" src="/d8/ctsandbox/sites/ctsandbox/files/Bonnie/combine660X300_0.jpg" />
```

The produced HTML:

```
<figure role="group" class="align-center"><img alt="Some alt text" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" src="/d8/ctsandbox/sites/ctsandbox/files/Bonnie/combine660X300_0.jpg"><figcaption>Woot, a caption!</figcaption></figure>
```

The problem is the `figure` is still block level and thus 100% width of the content area. The result.

[image]

It is centered in the editor itself, before I save it, and I noticed `<figure>` has a class `caption` which applies `display: table`.

[image]

However looking at the FilterCaption plugin, it appears to be doing what it is supposed to.

What am I missing? Why is the figure 100% and not the same width as the image, so it can be centering using `align-center` class that it has (and presumably is supposed to have)?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The easiest "fix" for your issue would be adding the missing styles to your front-end theme, e.g. `figure.align-center { text-align: center; }`.

Comment: PS.: I didn't add a fully-fledged answer, as I'm still wondering, whether this really is a Drupal related question suitable for Drupal Answers, or a generic HTML/CSS question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mario. I get your concern it is indeed solvable with just CSS. However after reading through https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2014895 I was under the impression that this functionality was baked into core. So, I searched around for more answers and didn't find any so I wanted to post here to make sure there isn't some underlying issue I'm dealing with that is preventing core functionality from working. If it turns out it's not part of core functionality and I have to add my own CSS I'd gladly remove this question if it's not worth leaving up.